# ChatterBox generates spacy error - can't find model 'en'

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, conda, spacy, chatterbot

Trying to build a sample chatbot using Python's chatterbot. I am using conda for virtual environment and Jupyter to run the code.

I have installed and tried to run the chatterbot according to this post:

[Can not install chatterbot in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268480/can-not-install-chatterbot-in-anaconda)

However, after running the following command:

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('Ron Obvious')
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I have looked at these solutions:   h[ttps://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1736](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1736)
[OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61410527/oserror-e050-cant-find-model-en-it-doesnt-seem-to-be-a-shortcut-link-a)

... and per instructions, installed the following:

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_md
python -m spacy link en_core_web_md en
```

after which I got the message:

```
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
```

and

```
You can now load the model via spacy.load('en')
```

However, the code still generates the same error. I have checked the conda environment, and it does have the following (from Jupyter):

```
!conda list -n py37_chatterbot

...
chatterbot                1.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
chatterbot-corpus         1.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
spacy                     3.0.5            py37h3b38789_0    conda-forge
spacy-legacy              3.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
...
```

Where should I go from here troubleshooting this issue?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, getting the same error. I have spacy 3.0.5, but running the code after installing installing en_core_web_sm produces the same message

Comment: You do not only have to install the model, you need to modify the `tagging.py` file.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have python3.7 in my virtual env, system runs on 3.9. Where would I find tagging.py?

Comment: "*"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 13*" - you will find it in your venv folder.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew worked like a charm! If you post it as an answer, I'll accept. Thanks!