# Error in installing dependencies of spacy

Tags: python, installation, chatterbot

```
Using cached spacy-2.1.8.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
```

Installing build dependencies ...error

> why this type of error, I reinstalled the latest Python and directly try installing chatterbot by using `pip install chatterbot`.

Comment: More detail about the error?

Comment: You need to provide _more_ details about the error. Which command/s did you run? What is your environment (OS, python version)? What are the other parts of the error message? (it usually displays more informative error than just "error").

Comment: Please add more detail!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use anaconda. Miniconda has a much smaller footprint than Anaconda. I would suggest installing miniconda.

Install Miniaconda on your system from [here](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). For instance if you are on linux, you could install miniconda using command as shown [here](https://waylonwalker.com/install-miniconda/).

Then create a new environment and install the necessary libraries as follows:

```sh
# Create and activate an environment by the name (nlp_env)
conda create -n nlp_env python=3.8 -yq
conda activate nlp_env

# Install spacy from conda-forge channel
conda install spacy -c conda-forge -y

# Install chatterbot
pip install chatterbot
pip install chatterbot-corpus
```

### References

- [Can not install chatterbot in Anaconda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56268480/can-not-install-chatterbot-in-anaconda)

Comment: While it is fine to suggest that Conda might make for a smoother installation, retagging the question with Conda-related tags does not seem warranted. OP is clearly using Pip and never mentioned Conda.

Comment: @merv You can use `pip` inside `conda`. So, someone trying to use `pip` can still use `conda` as an environment manager and install packages with `pip`. In fact there are a lot of packages which do not provide any conda-alternative. And then your only option is to use pip either from PyPI or from the repo to install the package.

Comment: @CypherX The point is not whether pip can be used with conda. The point is just because you provided an _answer_ using conda, that does not mean the _question_ should be retagged with conda. That could limit the answers to just conda, even though OP didn't indicate that anywhere in the question. See related [Should a question be retagged to include a topic mentioned in an answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/281783/2745495).

Comment: @GinoMempin I see the point. Thank you, for making it clear. Much appreciated. :)